# Horrible performance in Firefox when anything is overlaid on imagery

Tags: html, css

So Firefox seems to grind to a halt when rendering an element transition/animation above an image. Safari, Chrome and even IE on the other hand are totally fine with it (a good example I've found is [here](https://rothelowman.com.au/insights/) - hover over one of the articles). Throw any CSS filters into the mix and it's a disaster.

The ol' *translateZ(0px)* method doesn't seem to help at all, nor do any of the other tricks that offset painting to the GPU. Is anyone aware of a solution to this, or is that sort of just what Firefox does?

Comment: See if there's a bug at mozilla.

Comment: Example looks good on a Win10 Pro x64/Fx 56 (old) (lots of MHz, RAM and real GPU). Though background images take forever to load from France. Did you test with another computer / OS?

Comment: I haven't tried Windows yet, but all 2017 MacBook Pros seem to have some real trouble with it. Good to know it's not totally across the board, though. Cheers Felipe.